# code is experiencing issues while USSD dialing

Tags: c#, .net

I need to develop a desktop application which detects all the connected 3g supported modems and then allow to dial USSD on them. USSD should be dial only once which will automatically dialed on every modem and then shows the response from them in data grid view.
I have written a code but i am experiencing issues.

```
if (cboPort.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter USSD command", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
else
{
    string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    try
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = ports[i];

            serialPort1.Open();

            if (serialPort1.IsOpen && counter != 0)
            {
                serialPort1.WriteLine(cboPort.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                
                bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = cboPort.Text;
                bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "";
                bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
                
            }
            serialPort1.Close();
            
        }
        cboPort.Clear();

        if (counter == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Modem Available", "Command Not Sent!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I think you should edit the formatting of the code because it does not look right.

Comment: How to do that, please can you do that for me

Comment: Ah, someone already fixed it for you :) Don't worry, when you earn more credits you'll automatically get more rights to manage your (and others) content on this site.

Comment: means my code is correct.

Comment: Perhaps you should first elaborate a bit on what issues you are experiencing. You have a variable `total` which I assume should be `ports.size()`. If you get exceptions then it's nice to know which ones you get.

Comment: total tells the ports.Size(). The issue i am experiencing is that when i send a USSD command to modem it don't executes